# How To Get Chunk To Query Builder In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

My `Database` Large Record How to Write `Chunk` In This Query

```
$users = DB::table('products')->orderBy($sortbysql, $sortbysqltype)
  -> where('product_name', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
  -> where('product_status', '=','1')
  -> paginate($view);

$querylistbrand = DB::table('products')->select('product_brand_name',     DB::raw('count(*) as total')) 
   -> where('product_name', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%') 
   -> where('product_status', '=','1')
   -> groupBy('product_brand_name')`enter code here`
   -> orderBy('total', 'desc')->take(25)->get();
```

Comment: If you just want to paginate or take(25) you dont need chunk

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is not necessary to chunk the results, since they are already being chunked by the methods `paginate` and `take`.

For both methods, you just have to provide an amount of records that will be retrieved:

```
$results = $query->paginate(15);
$results = $query->take(15)->get();
```